# Kendo UI Grouping with Column Menu

Tags: kendo-ui

I am facing an issue while using Kendo gird with both grouping & column menu enabled.

when we select any one of the columns for grouping(say ShipCountry) ,collapse all the rows,de-select any column from the columns menu(right corner of columns) and expand the rows .
the de-selected columns are visible in the inner grid & the column name is not visible in the header.

we even tried handling the check events of the columns menu ,show or hide columns manually 
but that did not work out.Can some body help to fix this issue.

Below is the code snippet of my implementation.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipCountry: { type: "string" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        ShipAddress: { type: "string" }                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 10,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 250,
                        sortable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        columnMenu: true,
                        pageable: true,
            groupable:true,
                        columns: [
                            "OrderID",
                            "ShipCountry",
                            "ShipName",
                            {
                                field: "ShipAddress",
                                filterable: false
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm this is a bug. I have logged it for fixing.

Comment: Any Temporary Quick fix ,to handle this case

Comment: For some reason I can no longer reproduce that bug. Could you please try this demo: http://jsbin.com/iqusal/3/edit? Let me know if you can reproduce it there (and the steps you took).

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue

Comment: 1.order by ShipCountry
2.From the column options de select ShipName and other column

Comment: Just want to add that this is also happening when using grid views that has ColumnMenu + ClientRowTemplate utilized at the same time.